# Laravel 5.4 controllers and models are read only files i can't edit them

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

Every time i want to edit laravel 5.4 controller Ubuntu ask's me for the password and when i make a new controller via PHP artisan make:controller TestController  it's read only how can i fix this?

Comment: Change the respective file permissions and avoid `composer install` as a root user

Answer (score 2):

it's nothing to do with laravel I think. check ubuntu directory permissions and remember **NOT** to use `composer` as root as [recommended by composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-to-install-untrusted-packages-safely.md)

Comment: thank you , but this worked for me 
sudo chmod 777 storage/ -R